# Theory - Can we consider a callable PHP being a runnable?

Tags: php, runnable, callable

coming from the Java world, a Runnable functional interface is used to represent a piece of runnable (executable) code.

In PHP, however, there's the **callable** type hint http://php.net/manual/it/language.types.callable.php which can be used to *type hint* an *anonymous function (closure)*, a *function name (given as a string)*, a method of either a static class or an instance (given as an array("Class", "staticMethod") or array($instance, 'instanceMethod')).

Of course Java's Runnable can't return values (it's `run()` method signature has `void` as return type), but as in PHP closures, functions or methods are actually "ran", "executed", call it how you want, can we assert that we can consider a Java Runnable (despite of the return value and inner implementation, how actually it is executed) a PHP callable?

P.S: Java has also a Callable interface, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html, and its documentation states:

> The Callable interface is similar to Runnable, in that both are
>   designed for classes whose instances are potentially executed by
>   another thread. A Runnable, however, does not return a result and
>   cannot throw a checked exception.

So if repeating the tour, a Runnable is similar to a Callable in Java as they both represent runnable code, in PHP there's no Runnable or Callable interface, but there's a callable type hint which represents closures, functions and methods, can we theoretically consider it a runnable, as it represent executable code too?

Thanks for the attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is my understanding that a callable represents some form of data the php interprets to be a method invocation. It does not mean that a callable has immediately executable code, java's does.

PHP will then take what parameters it has and goes and FINDS the code and executes it. I think that is the biggest difference. Sometimes there is immediately executable code, sometimes it has to lookup where the code is "\someclass::somestaticmethod"

My thoughts.

Comment: This is true, however as in PHP there's not an explicit built-in runnable type hint, doens't the callable type hint resemble as much as possible to the Runnable behaviour as a code being (even if not immediately) executed?

Comment: you can sort of mimic it with the is_callable() but its not ideal.

Answer (score 1):

PHP's callable is more similar to Java's [`Method`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html) class in reflection. You can call `call_user_func()` on callable, and `invoke()` the `Method` object, both with parameters. Value is returned from both. And most important, where `Runnable` differs, it's designed to run in the same thread.

Remember that `Runnable` implementing class is plain POJO, there's not much special about it. The interface only makes it possible to pass to `Thread` constructor.

Comment: That's cool, but why did you say `where Runnable differs, it's designed to run in the same thread`, I know that a Runnable in Java runs in the same thread unless wrapped in a `new Thread(new Runnable(){//etc...}).start();'`, but even a function or a method in PHP runs in the same thread, unless something like `pthreads` is used...

Comment: You are right, I should have said "meant", `Runnable` is meant to run in different thread, as `Thread` is the class that expects it. After all, it's possible to wrap `Method` inside `Runnable`, `Runnable` inside `Method`.

Answer (score 1):

Java's `Runnable` is a pure interface, which can cooperate with some classes including `Thread`.

PHP's `callable` is a pseudo type for type hinting. It is a "magic" contract which ensures that it is safe to call the parameter variable as a function.

If you want to use an OOP interface, then use `Closure`. Some frameworks also use `Closure` instead of `callable`.

For example, see [Laravel Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#route-parameters).

Furthermore, a major difference that `Runnable` can be only invoked without parameters, while a `callable` parameter can be any functor with any number of parameters. Java is more strict, however you can define a more or less universal callable type:

```
public interface Callable {

    public Object call(Object... parameters);

}
```

Of course, in the case of a strongly typed language this does not make much sense.